# Reset windows 10 user profile periodically

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I have a windows 10 pc for presentation purposes. I want tot reset the profile and clean the desktop, my documents etc periodically. 
Preferably every time windows boots up.

This way if a person forgets files on the presentation pc they are deleted so no sensitive can be seen by others.

I remember such an option in the NT 4 days, but I it's been so long ago.

Comment: There is software specifically designed to keep a machine in a specific state once it's configured.  Only an Administrator can unlock the configure, allowing updates to be installed, there is no feature within Windows that will accomplish what you want though.

Comment: Consider  to create and use a VM's snapshot (virtual machine)

Comment: @duDE That's not an option. I want to be able to install and configure on the box, it's only the user profile that needs "resetting".

Comment: @Ramhound If third party software is needed so be it. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You can always create a mandatory profile and set a local policy to delete cached copy on each logout